# Specifying a required TypeScript version

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

Suppose I'm a JavaScript library author who includes TypeScript typings (a `.d.ts` file) within my project, and those typings require features that were added in a particular TypeScript version.  How do I communicate that TypeScript version dependency to users of my library?

TypeScript isn't a dependency of my library itself, so adding it as to my library's package.json's `dependencies` isn't correct, and any projects using my library (rightfully) don't care that I've specified a particular TS version in `devDependencies`.  Saying "this library conflicts with TypeScript < version foo" would work, but package.json doesn't seem to have a "conflicts" feature like some other package managers do.

I've checked the TypeScript documentation and can't find anything describing how to do this.  So far, the best I've been able to come up with is let the compile fail and hope that the resulting error messages are clear enough in communicating that any projects using my library need to upgrade their installed version of TypeScript.

Comment: Starting with 3.1 you can have different type definitions based on version. So you could have a default that is empty or in some way produces a better error for below 3.1 and have the good definitions in the 3.1 and above versions. Not ideal but I think that is best we can do (but I might be wrong). https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22605